# Are we able to Convert Xamain.iOS custom control to Xamarin.Forms Custom control? If yes then how?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have requirement to show badge notification icon on NavigationBar right side 
for which I have used below code in my native **Xamari.iOS** project but now I wanted it to use in **Xamarin.Forms** as Custom Control.

Could someone help me to create Renderer for iOS and Android this type of Custom Controls in **Xamarin.Forms**?

```
 using System;
    using UIKit;
    using CoreGraphics;
    using CoreAnimation;
    using Foundation; 

    namespace App1.iOS
    {
        public class BadgeBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem 
        {
            #region Fields

            UILabel _badge;

            string _badgeValue;

            UIColor _badgeBGColor;
            UIColor _badgeTextColor;
            UIColor _badgeBorderColor;

            UIFont _badgeFont;

            nfloat _badgePadding;
            nfloat _badgeMinSize;
            nfloat _badgeOriginX;
            nfloat _badgeOriginY;
            nfloat _badgeBorderWidth;

            bool _shouldHideBadgeAtZero;
            bool _shouldAnimateBadge;

            #endregion

            #region Public properties



            // Each time you change one of the properties, the badge will refresh with your changes

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the badge value to be displayed.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The badge value.</value>
            public string BadgeValue
            {
                get
                {
                    return _badgeValue;
                }
                set
                {
                    _badgeValue = value;
                    SetBadgeValue(value);
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the badge background color.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The color of the badge background.</value>
            public UIColor BadgeBGColor
            {
                get
                {
                    return _badgeBGColor;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (value == null)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BadgeBGColor));
                    _badgeBGColor = value;
                    if (_badge != null)
                    {
                        this.RefreshBadge();
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the badge text color.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The color of the badge text.</value>
            public UIColor BadgeTextColor
            {
                get
                {
                    return _badgeTextColor;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (value == null)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BadgeTextColor));
                    _badgeTextColor = value;
                    if (_badge != null)
                    {
                        this.RefreshBadge();
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the badge border color.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The color of the badge border.</value>
            public UIColor BadgeBorderColor
            {
                get
                {
                    return _badgeBorderColor;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (value == null)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BadgeBorderColor));
                    _badgeBorderColor = value;
                    if (_badge != null)
                    {
                        this.RefreshBadge();
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the badge font.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The badge font.</value>
            public UIFont BadgeFont
            {
                get
                {
                    return _badgeFont;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (value == null)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BadgeFont));
                    _badgeFont = value;
                    if (_badge != null)
                    {
                        this.RefreshBadge();
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the padding value for the badge.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The badge padding.</value>
            public nfloat BadgePadding
            {
                get
                {
                    return _badgePadding;
                }
                set
                {
                    _badgePadding = value;
                    if (_badge != null)
                    {
                        this.UpdateBadgeFrame();
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the minimum size of the badge minimum.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The minimum size of the badge.</value>
            public nfloat BadgeMinSize
            {
                get
                {
                    return _badgeMinSize;
                }
                set
                {
                    _badgeMinSize = value;
                    if (_badge != null)
                    {
                        this.UpdateBadgeFrame();
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the X value for offsetting the badge over the BarButtonItem.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The badge X origin.</value>
            public nfloat BadgeOriginX
            {
                get
                {
                    return _badgeOriginX;
                }
                set
                {
                    _badgeOriginX = value;
                    if (_badge != null)
                    {
                        this.UpdateBadgeFrame();
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the Y value for offsetting the badge over the BarButtonItem.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The badge Y origin.</value>
            public nfloat BadgeOriginY
            {
                get
                {
                    return _badgeOriginY;
                }
                set
                {
                    _badgeOriginY = value;
                    if (_badge != null)
                    {
                        this.UpdateBadgeFrame();
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the width of the badge border.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The badge border width.</value>
            public nfloat BadgeBorderWidth
            {
                get
                {
                    return _badgeBorderWidth;
                }
                set
                {
                    _badgeBorderWidth = value;
                    if (_badge != null)
                    {
                        this.RefreshBadge();
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="Utility.BadgeBarButtonItem"/> should remove the badge when reaching zero.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value><c>true</c> if should hide badge at zero; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
            public bool ShouldHideBadgeAtZero
            {
                get
                {
                    return _shouldHideBadgeAtZero;
                }
                set
                {
                    _shouldHideBadgeAtZero = value;
                    if (_badge != null)
                    {
                        this.UpdateBadgeFrame();
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="Utility.BadgeBarButtonItem"/> should animate the badge when its value changes.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value><c>true</c> if should animate badge; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
            public bool ShouldAnimateBadge
            {
                get
                {
                    return _shouldAnimateBadge;
                }
                set
                {
                    _shouldAnimateBadge = value;
                    if (_badge != null)
                    {
                        this.UpdateBadgeFrame();
                    }
                }
            }

            #endregion

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Utility.BadgeBarButtonItem"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="customButton">Custom button.</param>
            public BadgeBarButtonItem(UIButton customButton)
            {
                this.CustomView = customButton;
                if (this.CustomView != null)
                {
                    Initializer();
                }
            }

            protected virtual void Initializer()
            {
                // Default design initialization
                this.BadgeBGColor = UIColor.Red;
                this.BadgeBorderColor = UIColor.White;
                this.BadgeTextColor = UIColor.White;
                this.BadgeFont = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(12);
                this.BadgePadding = 6;
                this.BadgeMinSize = 8;
                this.BadgeOriginX = 7;
                this.BadgeOriginY = -9;
                this.BadgeBorderWidth = 0;
                this.ShouldHideBadgeAtZero = true;
                this.ShouldAnimateBadge = true;
                // Avoids badge to be clipped when animating its scale
                this.CustomView.ClipsToBounds = false;
            }

            #region Utility methods

            // Handles badge display when its properties have been changed (background, color and font)
            void RefreshBadge()
            {
                // Change new attributes
                _badge.TextColor = this.BadgeTextColor;
                _badge.BackgroundColor = this.BadgeBGColor;
                _badge.Font = this.BadgeFont;

                SetBorder();
            }

            void UpdateBadgeFrame()
            {
                // When the value changes the badge could need to get bigger
                // Calculate expected size to fit new value
                // Use an intermediate label to get expected size thanks to sizeToFit
                // We don't call sizeToFit on the true label to avoid bad display
                UILabel frameLabel = DuplicateLabel(_badge);

                frameLabel.SizeToFit();

                CGSize expectedLabelSize = frameLabel.Frame.Size;

                // Make sure that for small value, the badge will be big enough
                nfloat minHeight = expectedLabelSize.Height;

                // Using a const we make sure the badge respect the minimum size
                minHeight = (minHeight < this.BadgeMinSize) ? this.BadgeMinSize : expectedLabelSize.Height;
                nfloat minWidth = expectedLabelSize.Width;
                nfloat padding = this.BadgePadding;

                // Using const we make sure the badge doesn't get too smal
                minWidth = (minWidth < minHeight) ? minHeight : expectedLabelSize.Width;
                _badge.Frame = new CGRect(this.BadgeOriginX, this.BadgeOriginY, minWidth + padding, minHeight + padding);
                _badge.Layer.CornerRadius = (minHeight + padding) / 2;
                _badge.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            }

            // Handle the badge changing value
            void UpdateBadgeValueAnimated(bool animated)
            {
                // Bounce animation on badge if value changed and if animation authorized
                if (animated && this.ShouldAnimateBadge && _badge.Text != this.BadgeValue)
                {
                    var animation = new CABasicAnimation();
                    animation.KeyPath = @"transform.scale";
                    animation.From = NSObject.FromObject(1.5);
                    animation.To = NSObject.FromObject(1);
                    animation.Duration = 0.2;
                    animation.TimingFunction = new CAMediaTimingFunction(0.4f, 1.3f, 1f, 1f);
                    _badge.Layer.AddAnimation(animation, @"bounceAnimation");
                }

                // Set the new value
                _badge.Text = this.BadgeValue;

                // Animate the size modification if needed
                double duration = animated ? 0.2 : 0;
                UIView.Animate(duration, UpdateBadgeFrame);
            }

            static UILabel DuplicateLabel(UILabel labelToCopy)
            {
                var duplicateLabel = new UILabel(labelToCopy.Frame);
                duplicateLabel.Text = labelToCopy.Text;
                duplicateLabel.Font = labelToCopy.Font;

                return duplicateLabel;
            }

            void RemoveBadge()
            {
                if (_badge != null)
                {
                    // Animate badge removal
                    UIView.AnimateNotify(0.15f, 0.0F,
                        UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn,
                        () => {
                            _badge.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(0.1f, 0.1f);
                        },
                        completed => {
                            _badge.RemoveFromSuperview();
                            _badge = null;
                        }
                    );
                }
            }

            #endregion

            #region Setter

            void SetBadgeValue(string badgeValue)
            {
                // Set new value
                _badgeValue = badgeValue;

                // When changing the badge value check if we need to remove the badge
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(badgeValue) || (badgeValue == @"0" && this.ShouldHideBadgeAtZero))
                {
                    RemoveBadge();
                }
                else if (_badge == null)
                {
                    // Create a new badge because it doesn't exist
                    _badge = new UILabel(new CGRect(this.BadgeOriginX, this.BadgeOriginY, 20, 20))
                    {
                        TextColor = this.BadgeTextColor,
                        BackgroundColor = this.BadgeBGColor,
                        Font = this.BadgeFont,
                        TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
                    };
                    // Fix for iOS 9: Correctly apply the CornerRadius later on
                    _badge.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;

                    SetBorder();

                    this.CustomView.AddSubview(_badge);
                    this.UpdateBadgeValueAnimated(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.UpdateBadgeValueAnimated(true);
                }
            }

            void SetBorder()
            {
                if (this.BadgeBorderWidth > 0)
                {
                    _badge.Layer.BorderColor = BadgeBorderColor.CGColor;
                }

                _badge.Layer.BorderWidth = this.BadgeBorderWidth;
            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
```

I got this control from below link please refer it:-
https://github.com/fabiogaragiola/BadgeBarButtonItem

Answer (score 0):

You should create custom renderer for page, then in OnElementChange you can call `this.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = barButton;` to add your custom toolbar button.